# Django TastyPie Geo Distance Lookups

Tags: django, distance, tastypie, geo

I'm using TastyPie for Geo-distance lookups. That is a bit difficult, because oficially its not supported by TastyPie. On Github (https://gist.github.com/1067176) I found the following code-sample:

```
 def apply_sorting(self, objects, options=None):
     if options and "longitude" in options and "latitude" in options:
         return objects.distance(Point(float(options['latitude']), float(options['longitude']))).order_by('distance')

     return super(UserLocationResource, self).apply_sorting(objects, options)
```

It works well, but now I would like to have the distance as a field result in TastyPie. Do you have any idea how to do that? Just including "distance" in the fields attribute doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fields defined in the meta attributes aren't enough to have the additional values returned.
They need to be defined as additional fields in the resource:

```
distance = fields.CharField(attribute="distance", default=0, readonly=True)
```

This value can be filled by defining `dehydrate_distance` method inside the resource

```
def dehydrate_distance(self, bundle):
    # your code here
```

or by adding some additional elements to queryset in resources meta like so:

```
queryset = YourModel.objects.extra(select={'distance': 'SELECT foo FROM bar'})
```

Tastypie itself appends a field called resource_uri that isn't actually present in the queryset, looking at the source code of tastypie's resources might be helpful for you too.

Comment: That works! Thanks so much for that, it's exactly what I wanted! The value is actually be filled in by the .distance() geodjango function, so I just had to add that field definition. Once again, thanks!